Singularity error when solving Poisson-Nernst-Planck equation
I am trying to solve the Poisson-Nernst-Planck equation in the form similar to eqns 9 and 10 in this research paper.

To simplify matter, I only consider single ion species ($i=1$) for $\rho_e$, where $\rho_e$ is defined as

As a simple start, I apply Dirichlet boundary condtions for $\psi$ and $c_i$, as well as zero flux condition ($j=0$). For $\psi$, I first utilize zero dirichlet values for left and right end of the domain ($\psi(x_L)=\psi(x_R)=0$). However, I plan to use non-zero flux ($j\neq0$) and non-zero dirichlet values for $\psi$ (i.e. $\psi(x_L)\neq\psi(x_R)\neq0$) for more advanced modelling.
Here is my code:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*Parameters*)
kB = 1.380649*10^-23; 
absTemp = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absTemp);
eps0 = 8.8541878128*10^(-12);
eps = 78.6;
e = 1.60217663*10^(-19);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
dfsvt = 1.33*10^(-9);
xRef = 10*10^(-10);
rhoRef = 10^3*nA;
rhoFStarVal = 1;(*normalized fixed charge concentration*)
rhoBStarVal = 1;(*normalized bulk concentration*)
tRef = 10*10^(-2);
xL = 0;(*in xRef*)
xMemL = 4; (*in xRef*)
xMemR = 8;(*in xRef*)
xR = 12;(*in xRef*)
stepFunc[x_] = 0.5*(Tanh[20*x] + 1);
filterFunc[x_] = stepFunc[x - xMemL]*stepFunc[-(x - xMemR)];
rhoFStar[x_] = rhoFStarVal* filterFunc[x];
zf = -1;
z1 = 1;(*Counter ion valence*)
z2 = -1;(*Co ion valence*)
deltaU = -1/beta;
vW = 30*10^(-30);
j = 0(*normalized conc/(m^2s)*);
debye2 = (kB*absTemp*eps*eps0)/(e^2*rhoRef);


(*Equations*)
elctrcTrnsprtV2 = 
 debye2/xRef^2*
   phi''[x] == -(zf*rhoFStarVal + z1*rho1fStar[x](*+z2*rho2fStar[
    x]*))
ctionTrnsprt = 
 rho1fStar'[x] == -z1*rho1fStar[x]*phi'[x] - (j*xRef)/dfsvt


(*NDSolve*)
totalSolV2 = 
 NDSolve[{ctionTrnsprt, elctrcTrnsprtV2, phi[xL] == 0, phi[xR] == 0, 
   rho1fStar[xL] == rhoBStarVal}, {phi, rho1fStar}, {x, 0, 1}]

NDSolve at untuned settings give the error as shown below:


Do you mean {x, xL, xR} instead of {x,0,1}?

@AlexTrounev Yes. I noticed there was a typo in my code.

We can use FEM to solve this problem as follows
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(*Parameters*)
kB = 1.380649*10^-23;
absTemp = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absTemp);
eps0 = 8.8541878128*10^(-12);
eps = 78.6;
e = 1.60217663*10^(-19);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
dfsvt = 1.33*10^(-9);
xRef = 10*10^(-10);
rhoRef = 10^3*nA;
rhoFStarVal = 1;(*normalized fixed charge concentration*)
rhoBStarVal = 1;(*normalized bulk concentration*)
tRef = 10*10^(-2);
xL = 0;(*in xRef*)
xMemL = 4; (*in xRef*)
xMemR = 8;(*in xRef*)
xR = 12;(*in xRef*)
stepFunc[x_] = 0.5*(Tanh[20*x] + 1);
filterFunc[x_] = stepFunc[x - xMemL]*stepFunc[-(x - xMemR)];
rhoFStar[x_] = rhoFStarVal*filterFunc[x];
zf = -1;
z1 = 1;(*Counter ion valence*)
z2 = -1;(*Co ion valence*)
deltaU = -1/beta;
vW = 30*10^(-30);
j = .0001(*normalized conc/(m^2s)*);
debye2 = (kB*absTemp*eps*eps0)/(e^2*rhoRef);


(*Equations*)
elctrcTrnsprtV2 = 
  phi''[x] == -(zf*rhoFStarVal + z1*rho1fStar[x])/(debye2/xRef^2);
ctionTrnsprt = 
  rho1fStar'[x] == -z1*rho1fStar[x]*phi'[x] - (j*xRef)/dfsvt;

bc = {DirichletCondition[{phi[x] == 0, rho1fStar[x] == rhoBStarVal}, 
   x == xL], 
  DirichletCondition[phi[x] == 0, x == xR]}; 
(*NDSolve*)

totalSolV2 = 
 NDSolve[Join[{ctionTrnsprt, elctrcTrnsprtV2}, bc], {phi, 
   rho1fStar}, {x, xL, xR}]

Visualization
{Plot[phi[x] /. totalSolV2[[1]], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "phi"], 
 Plot[rho1fStar[x] /. totalSolV2[[1]], {x, xL, xR}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "rho1fStar"]}



Hi Alex, I have introduced some changes and managed to partially solve the equations under certain parameters. However, the system exhibits numerical error as the boundary condition value increases. Details are in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/305384/unwanted-oscillation-in-solution-occurs-when-solving-poisson-nernst-planck-equat
Do you mind taking a look? To appreciate your response, I will accept the current solution.
