Unwanted Oscillation in Solution Occurs When Solving Poisson-Nernst-Planck Equation
This is a follow-up post for this question. I am trying to solve the Poisson-Nernst-Planck equation in the form similar to eqns 9 and 10 in this research paper.

Different than the previous question, I consider two ion species ($i=1,2$ and $z_1=1, z_1=-1$) for $\rho_e$, where $\rho_e$ is defined as

Compared with the previous question, I also made some changes to the boundary conditions/parameter value. I consider dirichlet boundary condition for $\varphi$, ($\varphi(x_L)=-u$ and $\varphi(x_R)=0$) and $c$, ($c_1=c_2=\overline{c}$). Then, $j_1 \neq 0$ and $j_2 = 0$
I managed to partially solve the previous question (only for certain parameter values)
Here is my code:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*Parameters*)
xRef = 10^(-8);
rhoRef = 0.1*nA;
j = 0.5; (*normalized conc/(m^2s)*)
rhoFStarVal = 120;(*normalized fixed charge concentration*)
rhoBStarVal = 20;(*normalized bulk concentration*)
phiBC = -0.25;(*in thermal voltage unit*)
kB = 1.380649*10^-23; 
absTemp = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absTemp);
eps0 = 8.8541878128*10^(-12);
eps = 78.6;
e = 1.60217663*10^(-19);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
dfsvt = 1.33*10^(-9);
xL = 0;(*in xRef*)
xMemL = 0.75; (*in xRef*)
xMemR = 1.25;(*in xRef*)
xR = 2;(*in xRef*)
stepFunc[x_] = 0.5*(Tanh[100*x] + 1);
filterFunc[x_] = stepFunc[x - xMemL]*stepFunc[-(x - xMemR)];
rhoFStar[x_] = rhoFStarVal* filterFunc[x];
zf = -1;
z1 = 1;(*Counter ion valence*)
z2 = -1;(*Co ion valence*)
deltaU = -1/beta;
vW = 30*10^(-30);
debye2 = (kB*absTemp*eps*eps0)/(e^2*rhoRef);

(*Equations*)
elctrcTrnsprtV2 = 
 debye2/xRef^2*
   phi''[x] == -(zf*rhoFStar[x] + z1*rho1fStar[x] + z2*rho2fStar[x])
ctionTrnsprt = 
 rho1fStar'[x] == -z1*rho1fStar[x]*phi'[x] - (j*xRef)/dfsvt
coionTrnsprt = rho2fStar'[x] == -z2*rho2fStar[x]*phi'[x]

(*NDSolve*)
totalSolV2 = 
 NDSolve[{ctionTrnsprt, coionTrnsprt, elctrcTrnsprtV2, phi[xL] == 0, 
   phi[xR] == phiBC, rho1fStar[xL] == rhoBStarVal, 
   rho2fStar[xL] == rhoBStarVal}, {phi, rho1fStar, rho2fStar}, {x, xL,
    xR},
  MaxStepSize->0.0001]

(*Define the concentration function concentration[r,t]*)
phiSol = totalSolV2[[1]][[1]][[2]];
rho1fStarSol = totalSolV2[[1]][[2]][[2]];
rho2fStarSol = totalSolV2[[1]][[3]][[2]];

(*Solution Plotting*)
Plot[phiSol[x], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "phi (KbT/e), steady"]
Plot[rho1fStarSol[x], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> {0, All}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Free Counter Ion (0.1 mM/L), steady"]
Plot[rho2fStarSol[x], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotLabel -> "Free Co Ion (0.1 mM/L), steady"]

Solving the system at rhoBStarVal=5 gives solution

with acceptable numerical residual (LHS-RHS)

However, when i set rhoBStarVal=20, I encountered this error

To solve for when rhoBStarVal=20, I also tried FEM method (Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",  "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00001}}}). It manages to output a set of results. However, the solution for rho2fStar exhibits oscillating behaviour, which looks wrong.


As one of the possibly solutions we can decrease accuracy and use explicit method as follows
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*Parameters*)
xRef = 10^(-8);
rhoRef = 0.1*nA;
j = 0.5; (*normalized conc/(m^2s)*)
rhoFStarVal = 120;(*normalized fixed charge concentration*)
rhoBStarVal = 20;(*normalized bulk concentration*)
phiBC = -0.25;(*in thermal voltage unit*)
kB = 1.380649*10^-23;
absTemp = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absTemp);
eps0 = 8.8541878128*10^(-12);
eps = 78.6;
e = 1.60217663*10^(-19);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
dfsvt = 1.33*10^(-9);
xL = 0;(*in xRef*)
xMemL = 0.75; (*in xRef*)
xMemR = 1.25;(*in xRef*)
xR = 2;(*in xRef*)
stepFunc[x_] = 0.5*(Tanh[100*x] + 1);
filterFunc[x_] = stepFunc[x - xMemL]*stepFunc[-(x - xMemR)];
rhoFStar[x_] = rhoFStarVal*filterFunc[x];
zf = -1;
z1 = 1;(*Counter ion valence*)
z2 = -1;(*Co ion valence*)
deltaU = -1/beta;
vW = 30*10^(-30);
debye2 = (kB*absTemp*eps*eps0)/(e^2*rhoRef);

(*Equations*)
elctrcTrnsprtV2 = 
 debye2/xRef^2*
   phi''[x] == -(zf*rhoFStar[x] + z1*rho1fStar[x] + z2*rho2fStar[x])
ctionTrnsprt = 
 rho1fStar'[x] == -z1*rho1fStar[x]*phi'[x] - (j*xRef)/dfsvt
coionTrnsprt = rho2fStar'[x] == -z2*rho2fStar[x]*phi'[x]

(*NDSolve*)

totalSolV2 = 
 NDSolve[{ctionTrnsprt, coionTrnsprt, elctrcTrnsprtV2, phi[xL] == 0, 
   phi[xR] == phiBC, rho1fStar[xL] == rhoBStarVal, 
   rho2fStar[xL] == rhoBStarVal}, {phi, rho1fStar, rho2fStar}, {x, xL,
    xR}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
  Method -> "ExplicitEuler"]


(*Define the concentration function concentration[r,t]*)
phiSol = totalSolV2[[1]][[1]][[2]];
rho1fStarSol = totalSolV2[[1]][[2]][[2]];
rho2fStarSol = totalSolV2[[1]][[3]][[2]];

(*Solution Plotting*)

{Plot[phiSol[x], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> "phi (KbT/e), steady"],
 Plot[rho1fStarSol[x], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> {0, All}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Free Counter Ion (0.1 mM/L), steady"],
 Plot[rho2fStarSol[x], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  PlotLabel -> "Free Co Ion (0.1 mM/L), steady"]} 


Second method is the Shooting method
sol2 = 
 NDSolve[{ctionTrnsprt, coionTrnsprt, elctrcTrnsprtV2, phi[xL] == 0, 
   phi[xR] == phiBC, rho1fStar[xL] == rhoBStarVal, 
   rho2fStar[xL] == rhoBStarVal}, {phi, rho1fStar, rho2fStar}, {x, xL,
    xR}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {phi[xL] == 0, phi'[xL] == -.7, 
      rho1fStar[xL] == rhoBStarVal, rho2fStar[xL] == rhoBStarVal}}]

Visualization
{Plot[phi[x] /. sol2[[1]], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> "phi (KbT/e), steady"],
 Plot[rho1fStar[x] /. sol2[[1]], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> {0, All}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Free Counter Ion (0.1 mM/L), steady"],
 Plot[rho2fStar[x] /. sol2[[1]], {x, xL, xR}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  PlotLabel -> "Free Co Ion (0.1 mM/L), steady"]}


